# Find an explicit atlas for this submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm having a hard time coming up with atlases for manifolds. I can prove using the implicit function theorem that

$M = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x_1^2+x_2^2=x_3^2+x_4^2=1\}$

is a $2$-dimensional manifold. I would like to find an explicit atlas for this manifold now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally this is a hard question, but in your example: Can you see what $M$ is diffeomorphic to?

Comment: I want to say to a torus, $S^1\times S^1$.

Comment: Can you find an atlas for $S^1$ then?

Comment: Is a torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$.                    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965654/distance-between-two-points-on-the-clifford-torus

Comment: Yep. I like the atlas that contains 4 open sets with projections. So, I guess I have 4 charts for each $S^1$ and then an atlas for $M$ should be exactly the Cartesian products of those charts.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so based on the comments, I think this should be the answer:

Let

$U_1=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in M: x_1>0\}, \phi_1:U_1\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_2$,

$U_2=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in M: x_2>0\}, \phi_2:U_2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1$,

$U_3=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in M: x_1<0\}, \phi_3:U_3\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_2$,

$U_4=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in M: x_2<0\}, \phi_4:U_4\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1$.

Then, we'll do the same thing with the third and the fourth components (calling them $V_j$ and $\psi_j$) and an atlas for $M$ should consist of $\{(U_i\times V_j,\phi_i\times \psi_j)\}_{i,j=1}^4$.

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Do you need to state the transition maps as well?  For instance, $\phi_1 \mathop{\scriptstyle\circ} \phi_2^{-1}(x_1) = \sqrt{1-x_1^2}$.

Comment: Yes, my major problem usually is coming up with an atlas. Thank you for the reminder though.

Comment: Also, as you know a manifold can have many atlases, so there are many correct answers.  This one looks correct, though.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the atlas that contains 4 charts for $S^1$ is my favorite one.

Comment: You do know that every torus has an atlas with two charts. If we let $U_1,U_2$ be the charts on $S^1$, then on $\mathbb{T}^n$ you can make $U_i\times\mathbb{T}^{n-1}$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$